# Advantage and disadvantage of Wilcoxon rank sum test compared to permutation test

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, permutation

What is the advantage and disadvantages of Wilcoxon rank sum test compared to permutation test? I want to know at least one each based on the shape of distribution of raw data.

Comment: A Wilcoxon Rank Sum test *is* a permutation test.

Comment: @Glen_b but a permutation test is not necessarily a Wilcoxon rank sum test. None of these comments will help the OP or another reader

Comment: @rep_ho Clearly, my comment indicates a need for clarification of the question.